# How to directly place SVG file content in the HTML to display it in a WordPress page

Tags: php, html, xml, image, svg

In the code below, line #31(xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"....) is where I put contents of an SVG file to display the text in a WordPress page. Please note this page is being rendered through advanced custom fields. Since VS code shows error in the line, I need your help in placing the contents in the right way. I would also appreciate if you could suggest a way to do it using Custom Field where I can just upload .svg file and access it directly in the HTML. Thank you.

```
<!-- START BANNER -->
<?php
$banner = get_field('static_banner');
$main_text = $banner['main_text'];
$image = $banner['background_image'];
$first_cta = $banner['first_cta'];
$second_cta = $banner['second_cta'];
?>
<div class="corp-hero relative corp-hero-img">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-md-6">
      <?php if($image): ?>
        <picture>
          <source media="(max-width: 480px)" srcset="<?php echo($image['sizes']['small']); ?>">
          <source media="(max-width: 1024px)" srcset="<?php echo($image['sizes']['medium']); ?>">
          <source media="(max-width: 1280px)" srcset="<?php echo($image['sizes']['large']); ?>">
          <source srcset="<?php echo($image['sizes']['xlarge']); ?>">
          <img src="<?php echo($image['sizes']['xlarge']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
        </picture>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-md-6 texts-and-cta-col">
      <div class="texts-and-cta">
        <?php if(stripos($main_text, "Do Not Display") === FALSE): ?>
          <h1 class="mb0 color-tan-dark">
            <?php if( $main_text ): echo $main_text; else: echo get_the_title(); endif; ?>
          </h1>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if( $main_text ): ?>
          <h2 class="mb2 mt2">
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><svg id="Layer_2" 

    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 626.03 244.21"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#fff;}</style></defs><g id="Layer_1-2"><g><g><path class="cls-1" d="M28.16,.58h22.88V6.7h-14.65V26.24h11.88v5.83h-11.88v21.64h14.79v5.9H28.16V.58Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M70.5,28.71L58.4,.58h7.65l8.96,20.84L83.18,.58h7.65l-12.39,28.79,12.97,30.24h-7.65l-9.62-22.23-8.31,22.23h-7.65l12.32-30.9Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M99.87,40.67V19.82C99.87,7.87,103.23,.07,115.76,.07c11,0,14.87,6.34,14.87,16.98v4.66h-7.8v-4.15c0-6.56-.15-11.08-7-11.08s-7.65,4.81-7.65,12.1v23.39c0,8.89,1.97,11.81,7.65,11.81,6.63,0,7-4.74,7-11.73v-4.37h7.8v4.37c0,10.86-3.28,18.22-14.87,18.22-12.53,0-15.89-8.6-15.89-19.6Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M142.51,.58h22.88V6.7h-14.65V26.24h11.88v5.83h-11.88v21.64h14.79v5.9h-23.03V.58Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M176.18,.58h14.65c10.57,0,14.58,6.05,14.58,16.32,0,9.4-4.88,15.23-14.5,15.23h-6.49v27.47h-8.23V.58Zm12.02,25.65c7.07,0,9.4-1.97,9.4-9.26,0-8.38-1.09-10.49-9.33-10.49h-3.86V26.24h3.79Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M221.65,6.7h-9.98V.58h27.91V6.7h-9.69V59.61h-8.23V6.7Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M249.71,.58h8.09V59.61h-8.09V.58Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M270.26,41.1V18.73c0-11.66,4.23-18.66,16.18-18.66s16.11,7.07,16.11,18.66v22.45c0,11.59-4.23,19.09-16.11,19.09s-16.18-7.43-16.18-19.17Zm23.98,1.82V17.05c0-6.56-1.24-10.57-7.8-10.57s-7.87,4.01-7.87,10.57v25.87c0,6.56,1.24,10.86,7.87,10.86s7.8-4.3,7.8-10.86Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M314.65,.58h5.61l16.76,39.21V.58h6.85V59.61h-5.25l-16.98-40.3V59.61h-7V.58Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M366.47,.58h7.94l12.61,59.03h-7.8l-2.7-14.87h-12.02l-2.84,14.87h-7.72L366.47,.58Zm8.96,38.26l-4.96-26.6-4.88,26.6h9.84Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M397,.58h8.23V53.71h15.09v5.9h-23.32V.58Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M448.16,41.61V18.58c0-11.3,3.13-18.58,14.94-18.58,10.57,0,14.28,6.12,14.28,16.98v2.04h-5.25v-2.04c0-8.31-1.75-12.53-8.96-12.53-8.16,0-9.4,5.68-9.4,13.55v24.27c0,8.6,1.82,13.63,9.47,13.63s9.26-5.03,9.26-13.77v-6.92h-8.75v-4.15h13.85v28.57h-3.57l-.66-6.71c-1.53,4.52-4.59,7.51-10.64,7.51-11.22,0-14.58-7.51-14.58-18.8Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M490.29,.58h5.54V59.61h-5.54V.58Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M509.23,.58h21.21V4.74h-15.67V26.96h13.04v4.08h-13.04v28.57h-5.54V.58Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M547.57,4.88h-11.15V.58h27.55V4.88h-10.86V59.61h-5.54V4.88Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M571.18,44.31l4.88-1.46c.8,7.29,2.7,12.97,9.91,12.97,5.25,0,8.31-2.55,8.31-8.53,0-5.25-2.77-8.53-7.21-12.75l-10.42-9.98c-3.79-3.57-5.39-7.29-5.39-11.88,0-8.16,5.32-12.68,13.34-12.68,8.53,0,13.34,4.08,14.14,14.94l-4.74,1.24c-.58-7.43-2.62-11.81-9.4-11.81-4.88,0-8.31,2.48-8.31,7.8,0,3.21,1.09,5.68,4.15,8.6l10.42,9.84c4.59,4.37,8.6,9.62,8.6,16.32,0,8.82-5.61,13.41-13.55,13.41-9.62,0-14.06-6.41-14.72-16.03Z"/></g><g><path class="cls-1" d="M57.52,176.63h-1.95c.39-1.89,.59-3.71,.59-5.47,0-3.91-1.21-7.01-3.61-9.33-2.41-2.31-5.86-3.47-10.35-3.47-3.52,0-6.36,.88-8.54,2.64-2.18,1.76-3.27,4.43-3.27,8.01,0,3,.89,5.81,2.69,8.45,1.79,2.64,4.51,5.91,8.15,9.81,2.73,2.87,4.88,5.27,6.44,7.23s2.9,4.1,4,6.44c1.11,2.34,1.66,4.82,1.66,7.42,0,4.36-1.4,8.01-4.2,10.94-2.8,2.93-6.27,5.09-10.4,6.49-4.13,1.4-8.25,2.1-12.35,2.1s-7.39-.36-9.67-1.07c-2.28-.72-4.69-1.86-7.23-3.42-1.43-.98-2.57-1.46-3.42-1.46s-1.51,.34-2,1.03-1.19,2.1-2.1,4.25H0c1.04-2.47,2.07-5.45,3.08-8.94,1.01-3.48,2.2-8.32,3.56-14.5h1.95c-.59,2.48-.88,4.79-.88,6.93,0,4.88,1.35,8.61,4.05,11.18,2.7,2.57,6.66,3.86,11.86,3.86,8.4,0,12.6-3.42,12.6-10.25,0-3.65-.86-6.92-2.59-9.81-1.73-2.9-4.31-6.23-7.76-10.01-2.34-2.67-4.2-4.9-5.57-6.69-1.37-1.79-2.52-3.82-3.47-6.1-.94-2.28-1.42-4.72-1.42-7.32,0-4.17,1.19-7.73,3.56-10.69,2.38-2.96,5.42-5.17,9.13-6.64,3.71-1.46,7.49-2.2,11.33-2.2,3.38,0,6.28,.39,8.69,1.17,2.41,.78,4.65,1.82,6.74,3.12,1.69,1.04,2.77,1.56,3.22,1.56,.52,0,1.03-.41,1.51-1.22,.49-.81,1.06-2.13,1.71-3.96h1.95c-2.47,6.25-4.39,12.89-5.76,19.92Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M65.86,195.09c2.44-5.79,6.05-10.64,10.84-14.55,4.79-3.91,10.5-5.86,17.14-5.86,5.08,0,8.98,1.38,11.72,4.15,2.73,2.77,4.1,6.75,4.1,11.96s-1.22,10.91-3.66,16.7c-2.44,5.79-6.05,10.64-10.84,14.55-4.78,3.91-10.5,5.86-17.14,5.86-5.08,0-8.98-1.38-11.72-4.15-2.73-2.77-4.1-6.75-4.1-11.96s1.22-10.9,3.66-16.7Zm19.58-11.52c-2.87,4.62-5.27,10.29-7.23,16.99-1.95,6.71-2.93,12.96-2.93,18.75,0,2.34,.26,4.04,.78,5.08,.52,1.04,1.37,1.56,2.54,1.56,2.41,0,5.03-2.25,7.86-6.74,2.83-4.49,5.22-10.07,7.18-16.75,1.95-6.67,2.93-13,2.93-18.99,0-2.54-.26-4.31-.78-5.32-.52-1.01-1.33-1.51-2.44-1.51-2.41,0-5.05,2.31-7.91,6.93Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M139.3,181.86c-3.03,3.48-5.49,8.04-7.37,13.67-1.89,5.63-2.83,11.41-2.83,17.33,0,6.51,2.47,9.76,7.42,9.76,4.69,0,8.98-2.86,12.89-8.59l1.95,.78c-2.34,3.78-5.32,6.9-8.94,9.37-3.61,2.47-7.73,3.71-12.35,3.71s-8.54-1.27-11.38-3.81c-2.83-2.54-4.25-6.28-4.25-11.23,0-5.6,1.4-11.38,4.2-17.33,2.8-5.96,6.74-10.92,11.82-14.89,5.08-3.97,10.84-5.96,17.28-5.96,3.58,0,6.46,.9,8.64,2.69,2.18,1.79,3.27,4.02,3.27,6.69,0,1.76-.42,3.48-1.27,5.18-.85,1.69-2.02,3.06-3.52,4.1-1.5,1.04-3.12,1.56-4.88,1.56-1.63,0-2.96-.52-4-1.56-1.04-1.04-1.56-2.41-1.56-4.1,0-2.54,.88-4.8,2.64-6.79,1.76-1.98,3.84-3.27,6.25-3.86-1.11-1.3-2.67-1.95-4.69-1.95-3.19,0-6.3,1.74-9.33,5.22Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M174.11,181.42c0-1.3-.59-1.95-1.76-1.95s-2.25,.6-3.22,1.81c-.98,1.21-1.99,3.17-3.03,5.91l-1.95,4.98h-1.86l2.73-7.42c2.41-6.7,6.93-10.06,13.57-10.06,2.99,0,5.18,.73,6.54,2.2s2.05,3.37,2.05,5.71c0,1.89-.36,3.81-1.07,5.76l-10.25,29.88c-.39,1.17-.59,2.12-.59,2.83,0,1.37,.65,2.05,1.95,2.05,.98,0,1.97-.55,2.98-1.66,1.01-1.11,2.07-3.12,3.17-6.05l1.76-4.69h1.86l-2.54,7.13c-2.28,6.71-6.67,10.06-13.18,10.06-5.92,0-8.89-2.7-8.89-8.11,0-2.15,.49-4.62,1.46-7.42l9.57-28.03c.46-1.5,.68-2.47,.68-2.93Zm5.96-28.03c1.89-1.56,4.23-2.34,7.03-2.34,2.28,0,4.05,.54,5.32,1.61,1.27,1.07,1.9,2.56,1.9,4.44,0,2.6-.98,4.75-2.93,6.45-1.95,1.69-4.36,2.54-7.23,2.54-2.34,0-4.13-.57-5.37-1.71-1.24-1.14-1.79-2.68-1.66-4.64,.06-2.67,1.04-4.79,2.93-6.35Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M240.61,210.71h1.85l-2.44,7.13c-1.3,3.65-3.11,6.24-5.42,7.76-2.31,1.53-4.8,2.29-7.47,2.29-3.39,0-5.79-1.01-7.23-3.03-.91-1.17-1.37-2.8-1.37-4.88,0-1.69,.29-3.61,.88-5.76-2.21,4.82-4.67,8.3-7.37,10.45-2.7,2.15-5.68,3.22-8.94,3.22-3.58,0-6.3-1.06-8.15-3.17-1.86-2.11-2.78-5.06-2.78-8.84,0-5.79,1.55-11.93,4.64-18.41,3.09-6.48,7.01-11.9,11.77-16.26,4.75-4.36,9.41-6.54,13.96-6.54,1.76,0,3.17,.52,4.25,1.56,1.07,1.04,1.71,2.6,1.9,4.69l1.37-4.79c5.21-.06,9.93-.55,14.16-1.46l-12.79,43.55c-.33,1.11-.49,2.02-.49,2.73,0,1.43,.62,2.15,1.85,2.15,2.28,0,4.3-2.57,6.05-7.71l1.76-4.69Zm-12.99-25.98c.06-.32,.1-.81,.1-1.46,0-1.63-.28-2.86-.83-3.71-.55-.85-1.38-1.27-2.49-1.27-2.21,0-4.74,1.99-7.57,5.96-2.83,3.97-5.24,8.95-7.23,14.94-1.99,5.99-2.98,11.78-2.98,17.38,0,2.15,.21,3.7,.63,4.64,.42,.94,1.12,1.42,2.1,1.42,1.43,0,3.01-.99,4.74-2.98,1.72-1.98,3.45-4.85,5.18-8.59,1.72-3.74,3.24-8.19,4.54-13.33l-.49,2.34,4.3-15.33Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M261.21,220.67c0,1.63,.68,2.44,2.05,2.44,2.02,0,3.97-2.57,5.86-7.71l1.76-4.69h1.86l-2.44,7.13c-1.24,3.65-3.03,6.24-5.37,7.76-2.34,1.53-4.88,2.29-7.62,2.29-2.93,0-5.14-.77-6.64-2.29-1.5-1.53-2.25-3.66-2.25-6.4,0-2.02,.39-4.3,1.17-6.83l15.33-50.97c.33-1.17,.49-2.08,.49-2.73,0-1.3-.5-2.25-1.51-2.83-1.01-.59-2.72-.88-5.13-.88l.68-2.05c4.49-.06,8.53-.42,12.11-1.07,3.58-.65,7.1-1.63,10.55-2.93l-20.51,69.33c-.26,.85-.39,1.66-.39,2.44Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M324.88,220.96c0,1.37,.47,2.28,1.42,2.73,.94,.46,2.69,.75,5.22,.88l-.39,1.95c-3.78-.2-9.08-.29-15.92-.29s-11.95,.1-15.33,.29l.49-1.95c2.28-.13,3.99-.39,5.13-.78,1.14-.39,2.05-1.16,2.73-2.29,.68-1.14,1.35-2.91,2-5.32l12.89-48.44c.52-2.21,.78-3.77,.78-4.69,0-1.43-.47-2.38-1.42-2.83-.94-.46-2.65-.75-5.13-.88l.49-1.95c3.19,.2,8.3,.29,15.33,.29,6.44,0,11.78-.1,16.01-.29l-.49,1.95c-2.41,.13-4.18,.39-5.32,.78-1.14,.39-2.05,1.14-2.73,2.25-.68,1.11-1.35,2.9-2,5.37l-12.89,48.44c-.59,2.47-.88,4.07-.88,4.78Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M421.85,210.71l-2.44,7.13c-2.34,6.71-6.74,10.06-13.18,10.06-3.78,0-6.38-1.17-7.81-3.52-.72-1.11-1.07-2.57-1.07-4.39,0-2.15,.49-4.69,1.46-7.62l8.79-26.37c.52-1.69,.78-2.99,.78-3.91,0-1.3-.46-1.95-1.37-1.95-2.67,0-5.88,3.21-9.62,9.62-3.74,6.41-7.5,15.74-11.28,27.98v-.29l-2.54,9.08h-13.96l11.91-40.53c.52-1.69,.78-3.03,.78-4,0-1.24-.52-1.85-1.56-1.85-2.93,0-6.23,3.39-9.91,10.16-3.68,6.77-7.15,15.59-10.4,26.46v-.1l-2.54,9.86h-13.77l11.91-42.19c.32-1.11,.49-2.05,.49-2.83,0-1.37-.59-2.05-1.76-2.05s-2.23,.6-3.17,1.81c-.94,1.21-1.94,3.17-2.98,5.91l-1.85,4.98h-1.86l2.64-7.42c1.3-3.58,3.11-6.15,5.42-7.71,2.31-1.56,4.9-2.34,7.76-2.34s4.82,.72,6.05,2.15c1.24,1.43,1.86,3.32,1.86,5.66,0,1.69-.29,3.65-.88,5.86l-2.15,8.4c3.19-7.94,6.46-13.61,9.81-16.99,3.35-3.38,7.37-5.08,12.06-5.08,5.14,0,7.71,2.54,7.71,7.62,0,1.82-.39,4.2-1.17,7.13l-1.76,6.25c3.25-7.75,6.56-13.18,9.91-16.31,3.35-3.12,7.21-4.69,11.57-4.69,2.73,0,4.75,.68,6.05,2.05,1.3,1.37,1.95,3.22,1.95,5.57,0,2.15-.46,4.53-1.37,7.13l-9.57,28.81c-.39,1.24-.59,2.18-.59,2.83,0,1.37,.62,2.05,1.86,2.05,2.21,0,4.26-2.57,6.15-7.71l1.76-4.69h1.86Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M478.14,178.54c2.05,2.57,3.08,6.3,3.08,11.18,0,5.34-1.19,10.99-3.56,16.94-2.38,5.96-5.78,10.99-10.2,15.09-4.43,4.1-9.57,6.15-15.43,6.15-1.82,0-3.52-.29-5.08-.88s-2.8-1.43-3.71-2.54l-2.64,9.38c-.39,1.37-.59,2.54-.59,3.51,0,1.82,.65,3.06,1.95,3.71,1.3,.65,3.35,1.01,6.15,1.07l-.59,2.05-2.25-.1c-6.64-.2-11.03-.29-13.18-.29s-6.74,.13-13.77,.39l.59-2.05c2.34,0,4.04-.42,5.08-1.27,1.04-.85,1.89-2.44,2.54-4.79l17.67-63.38c-1.82,4.04-3.91,7.67-6.25,10.89-2.34,3.22-5.21,6.56-8.59,10.01l-1.07-1.27c2.86-3.12,5.24-5.84,7.13-8.15,1.89-2.31,3.79-5.14,5.71-8.5,1.92-3.35,3.82-7.44,5.71-12.25l.29-1.17c5.27-.39,10.12-1.3,14.55-2.73l-8.4,29.78c2.34-5.08,4.82-8.79,7.42-11.13,2.6-2.34,5.4-3.52,8.4-3.52,3.97,0,6.98,1.29,9.03,3.86Zm-20.99,40.62c2.9-3.94,5.26-8.82,7.08-14.65,1.82-5.83,2.73-11.34,2.73-16.55,0-3.06-.28-5.18-.83-6.35-.55-1.17-1.35-1.76-2.39-1.76-1.95,0-4.17,1.89-6.64,5.66-2.48,3.78-4.75,8.56-6.84,14.35l-6.54,22.95c1.24,1.5,2.73,2.25,4.49,2.25,3.06,0,6.04-1.97,8.94-5.91Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M533.46,210.71h1.85l-2.44,7.13c-1.3,3.65-3.11,6.24-5.42,7.76-2.31,1.53-4.8,2.29-7.47,2.29-3.39,0-5.79-1.01-7.23-3.03-.91-1.17-1.37-2.8-1.37-4.88,0-1.69,.29-3.61,.88-5.76-2.21,4.82-4.67,8.3-7.37,10.45-2.7,2.15-5.68,3.22-8.94,3.22-3.58,0-6.3-1.06-8.15-3.17-1.86-2.11-2.78-5.06-2.78-8.84,0-5.79,1.55-11.93,4.64-18.41,3.09-6.48,7.01-11.9,11.77-16.26,4.75-4.36,9.41-6.54,13.96-6.54,1.76,0,3.17,.52,4.25,1.56,1.07,1.04,1.71,2.6,1.9,4.69l1.37-4.79c5.21-.06,9.93-.55,14.16-1.46l-12.79,43.55c-.33,1.11-.49,2.02-.49,2.73,0,1.43,.62,2.15,1.85,2.15,2.28,0,4.3-2.57,6.05-7.71l1.76-4.69Zm-12.99-25.98c.06-.32,.1-.81,.1-1.46,0-1.63-.28-2.86-.83-3.71-.55-.85-1.38-1.27-2.49-1.27-2.21,0-4.74,1.99-7.57,5.96-2.83,3.97-5.24,8.95-7.23,14.94-1.99,5.99-2.98,11.78-2.98,17.38,0,2.15,.21,3.7,.63,4.64,.42,.94,1.12,1.42,2.1,1.42,1.43,0,3.01-.99,4.74-2.98,1.72-1.98,3.45-4.85,5.18-8.59,1.72-3.74,3.24-8.19,4.54-13.33l-.49,2.34,4.3-15.33Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M566.22,181.86c-3.03,3.48-5.49,8.04-7.37,13.67-1.89,5.63-2.83,11.41-2.83,17.33,0,6.51,2.47,9.76,7.42,9.76,4.69,0,8.98-2.86,12.89-8.59l1.95,.78c-2.34,3.78-5.32,6.9-8.94,9.37-3.61,2.47-7.73,3.71-12.35,3.71s-8.54-1.27-11.38-3.81c-2.83-2.54-4.25-6.28-4.25-11.23,0-5.6,1.4-11.38,4.2-17.33,2.8-5.96,6.74-10.92,11.82-14.89,5.08-3.97,10.84-5.96,17.28-5.96,3.58,0,6.46,.9,8.64,2.69,2.18,1.79,3.27,4.02,3.27,6.69,0,1.76-.42,3.48-1.27,5.18-.85,1.69-2.02,3.06-3.52,4.1-1.5,1.04-3.12,1.56-4.88,1.56-1.63,0-2.96-.52-4-1.56-1.04-1.04-1.56-2.41-1.56-4.1,0-2.54,.88-4.8,2.64-6.79,1.76-1.98,3.84-3.27,6.25-3.86-1.11-1.3-2.67-1.95-4.69-1.95-3.19,0-6.3,1.74-9.33,5.22Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M602.79,218.23c-.2,.65-.29,1.3-.29,1.95,0,.98,.26,1.71,.78,2.2,.52,.49,1.24,.73,2.15,.73,1.43,0,2.81-.7,4.15-2.1,1.33-1.4,2.52-3.5,3.56-6.3l1.46-4h1.86l-1.95,5.66c-2.54,7.68-7.42,11.52-14.65,11.52-3.32,0-5.81-.86-7.47-2.59-1.66-1.72-2.49-4.08-2.49-7.08,0-1.89,.29-3.84,.88-5.86l9.86-34.37h-8.79l.49-1.95h8.89l4.2-14.55c5.53-.06,10.25-.52,14.16-1.37l-4.59,15.92h11.03l-.29,1.95h-11.33l-11.62,40.23Z"/></g><g><path class="cls-1" d="M289.99,106.44c0,1.82-.3,3.61-.89,5.37s-1.52,3.21-2.77,4.37-2.8,1.74-4.64,1.74-2.97-.69-3.58-2.06c-1.53,1.37-3.08,2.06-4.66,2.06-1.44,0-2.5-.37-3.17-1.1-.67-.73-1.01-1.65-1.01-2.75,0-1.91,.94-3.99,2.83-6.23s4.17-4.36,6.85-6.36c-.07,.02-.33,.18-.78,.47-.63,.38-1.13,.66-1.49,.83s-.7,.25-1.01,.25c-.27,0-.51-.07-.73-.2s-.34-.21-.39-.24c-.4-.27-.74-.41-1.01-.41-.36,0-.66,.15-.91,.46s-.5,.85-.74,1.64l-.41,1.25h-.64l.78-2.46c.41-1.26,.87-2.15,1.4-2.67,.53-.52,1.11-.78,1.74-.78,.29,0,.54,.05,.74,.15s.46,.26,.78,.49c.34,.23,.61,.39,.83,.51,.21,.11,.47,.17,.76,.17,.54,0,1.02-.08,1.45-.25,.43-.17,.84-.43,1.25-.79l.47-.64,.71,.34c-2.75,2.32-4.96,4.66-6.65,7.02-1.69,2.36-2.53,4.78-2.53,7.26,0,1.08,.16,1.86,.47,2.33,.31,.47,.78,.71,1.38,.71,.56,0,1.14-.13,1.74-.41,.6-.27,1.18-.67,1.74-1.21-.16-.63-.24-1.29-.24-1.99,0-1.26,.28-2.51,.83-3.75,.55-1.24,1.21-2.25,1.99-3.04,.78-.79,1.48-1.18,2.11-1.18,.45,0,.76,.24,.93,.71,.17,.47,.25,1.02,.25,1.65,0,1.22-.33,2.44-.98,3.68-.65,1.24-1.62,2.35-2.9,3.34,.52,1.49,1.42,2.23,2.7,2.23,1.44,0,2.66-.55,3.66-1.65,1-1.1,1.75-2.46,2.24-4.08,.49-1.62,.74-3.2,.74-4.73,0-.92-.08-1.67-.24-2.23-.81-.16-1.55-.49-2.21-1-.66-.51-1-1.18-1-2.01,0-.54,.14-.95,.42-1.22,.28-.27,.61-.4,1-.4,.63,0,1.15,.36,1.55,1.08,.4,.72,.72,1.69,.94,2.9,.18,.74,.27,1.69,.27,2.83Zm-8.88,.51c-.45,.58-.83,1.33-1.15,2.24-.32,.91-.47,1.83-.47,2.75,0,.81,.08,1.53,.24,2.16,1.01-.83,1.81-1.83,2.4-2.99,.58-1.16,.88-2.31,.88-3.46,0-1.06-.21-1.59-.64-1.59-.38,0-.8,.29-1.25,.88Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M298.23,101.72c0-.56-.25-.84-.74-.84s-.98,.27-1.38,.81c-.4,.54-.83,1.42-1.28,2.63l-.47,1.25h-.64l.88-2.46c.45-1.28,1.05-2.18,1.81-2.7,.75-.52,1.55-.78,2.38-.78,1.49,0,2.23,.71,2.23,2.13,0,.74-.18,1.61-.54,2.6l-3.61,10.23c-.18,.54-.27,.96-.27,1.25,0,.56,.27,.84,.81,.84,.47,0,.91-.26,1.32-.78,.4-.52,.84-1.41,1.32-2.67l.47-1.25h.64l-.88,2.46c-.45,1.24-1.04,2.13-1.77,2.67-.73,.54-1.52,.81-2.38,.81-1.58,0-2.36-.69-2.36-2.06,0-.65,.2-1.54,.61-2.67l3.61-10.23c.18-.54,.27-.96,.27-1.25Zm1.5-9.13c.51-.53,1.09-.79,1.74-.79,.52,0,.93,.17,1.25,.51,.31,.34,.47,.75,.47,1.25,0,.68-.26,1.27-.78,1.79-.52,.52-1.1,.78-1.76,.78-.5,0-.9-.16-1.21-.49-.32-.33-.47-.74-.47-1.23,0-.67,.25-1.28,.76-1.81Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M307.58,114.58c-.07,.27-.1,.52-.1,.74,0,.45,.13,.79,.4,1.01,.27,.23,.62,.34,1.05,.34,.56,0,1.09-.24,1.57-.73s.96-1.37,1.43-2.65l.47-1.32h.64l-.71,2.13c-.47,1.4-1.09,2.38-1.84,2.95-.75,.57-1.68,.86-2.78,.86-1.01,0-1.77-.25-2.26-.74-.5-.49-.74-1.18-.74-2.06,0-.58,.1-1.23,.3-1.92l3.58-12.42h-3.04l.17-.67h3.04l1.48-5.13c1.22-.04,2.23-.2,3.04-.47l-1.59,5.6h4.46l-.1,.67h-4.56l-3.92,13.8Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M331.92,111.98l-.84,2.46c-.81,2.32-2.17,3.48-4.08,3.48-1.58,0-2.36-.7-2.36-2.09,0-.67,.18-1.55,.54-2.63l3.21-9.65c.22-.63,.34-1.19,.34-1.69,0-.76-.36-1.15-1.08-1.15-.83,0-1.73,.52-2.68,1.57-.96,1.05-1.92,2.51-2.89,4.4-.97,1.89-1.87,4.08-2.7,6.58l-1.21,4.19h-2.94l6.68-22.51c.11-.38,.17-.69,.17-.91,0-.45-.18-.78-.54-1-.36-.21-.96-.32-1.79-.32l.2-.71c2.34-.02,4.37-.48,6.08-1.38l-4.89,16.74c1.22-2.75,2.43-4.72,3.65-5.92,1.21-1.2,2.54-1.81,3.98-1.81,1.82,0,2.73,.86,2.73,2.56,0,.72-.17,1.56-.51,2.53l-3.27,9.86c-.18,.54-.27,.97-.27,1.28,0,.54,.27,.81,.81,.81,.45,0,.88-.25,1.3-.76,.42-.51,.85-1.4,1.3-2.68l.44-1.25h.64Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M357.5,111.94h.64l-.84,2.46c-.45,1.24-1.02,2.13-1.72,2.68-.7,.55-1.42,.83-2.16,.83-.43,0-.8-.08-1.11-.24-.32-.16-.56-.37-.74-.64-.2-.34-.3-.73-.3-1.18,0-.47,.08-1,.24-1.59,.16-.58,.26-.96,.3-1.11l.61-2.43c-1.08,2.52-2.18,4.35-3.29,5.48-1.11,1.14-2.28,1.71-3.49,1.71-1.04,0-1.82-.37-2.36-1.11-.54-.74-.81-1.73-.81-2.97,0-1.82,.48-3.86,1.45-6.11,.97-2.25,2.23-4.16,3.78-5.74s3.13-2.36,4.73-2.36c.61,0,1.1,.22,1.49,.67,.38,.45,.61,1.08,.68,1.89l.54-2.09c1.24-.04,2.27-.2,3.1-.47l-4.22,14.92c-.02,.09-.07,.26-.13,.52-.07,.26-.1,.5-.1,.73,0,.56,.25,.84,.74,.84,.99,0,1.86-1.15,2.6-3.44l.41-1.25Zm-8.64,3.44c.88-.97,1.74-2.26,2.58-3.87,.84-1.61,1.54-3.32,2.08-5.15l.61-2.4c.02-.18,.03-.43,.03-.74,0-.92-.16-1.65-.49-2.18-.33-.53-.78-.79-1.37-.79-.97,0-1.99,.75-3.07,2.25s-1.99,3.34-2.72,5.54c-.73,2.19-1.1,4.26-1.1,6.19,0,.92,.1,1.59,.3,1.99,.2,.4,.5,.61,.88,.61,.63,0,1.38-.48,2.26-1.45Z"/></g><path class="cls-1" d="M258.2,109.26H29.54c-.55,0-1-.45-1-1s.45-1,1-1h228.66c.55,0,1,.45,1,1s-.45,1-1,1Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M597.54,109.26h-227.6c-.55,0-1-.45-1-1s.45-1,1-1h227.6c.55,0,1,.45,1,1s-.45,1-1,1Z"/></g></g></svg>
              </h2>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ( $first_cta ) : ?>
              <div class="shop-gifts-cta">
                <a href="<?php echo $first_cta['url']; ?>" class="btn cta-btn-gold-border" role="button" target="<?php echo $first_cta['target']; ?>" title="<?php echo $first_cta['title']; ?>">
                  <?php echo $first_cta['title']; ?>
                </a>
              </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ( $second_cta ) : ?>
              <div class="corporate-gifts-cta">
                <a href="<?php echo $second_cta['url']; ?>" class="btn cta-btn-gold-border" role="button" target="<?php echo $second_cta['target']; ?>" title="<?php echo $second_cta['title']; ?>">
                  <?php echo $second_cta['title']; ?>
                </a>
              </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END BANNER -->
```

Comment: You can start off by removing the XML declaration (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`). That is only for XML documents (and placed in the first line of the document).

Comment: The SVG element itself looks fine. All the elements have a white fill, but I guess that your background has a color, so that they show.

Comment: Removing `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` fixed. Thanks

Comment: Any idea if I can store this content in a custom field in the backend and read it just like other data in my code?

Comment: You can just insert the `<svg> ... </svg>` like any other dynamic string you have on the page.

Comment: Thanks, if you convert your comment into answer, I will accept it as it solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your lengthy SVG contents within . Hope you'll find this helpful